# Node.js oauth20 Bad Token issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
TokenError: Bad Request
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/home/ubuntu/workspace/React/fullstack-basics/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:329:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/React/fullstack-basics/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/React/fullstack-basics/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/React/fullstack-basics/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (/home/ubuntu/workspace/React/fullstack-basics/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/React/fullstack-basics/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:120:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:218:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1054:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
```

Here is my index.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
      passport = require('passport'),
      GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy,
      keys = require('./config/keys');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
    {
        clientID: keys.googleClientID,
        clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
    },
        accessToken => {
            console.log(accessToken);
        }
    )
);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('index'); 
});


app.get('/auth/google', 
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email']
    })
);

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'));


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, process.env.IP, () => {
    console.log('Server is listening..');  
});
```

**I am using C9**
My settings within the API app settings are as follows:

Authorized JavaScript origins -> http://learning-space-fvrthebrave.c9users.io
Authorized redirect URIs -> http://learning-space-fvrthebrave.c9users.io/auth/google/callback

I am stuck here and can't tell if it is an issue with my code or an issue with oauth!

Comment: Check if adding the complete url in google strategy callback_url works.

Comment: That worked, awesome. I guess this was sort of obvious haha